# Distribution of weight for a heavy table top

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, estimation

I've had a table base, 36"Wx29"Lx40"H, made for a heavy marble top, 59" x 64 3/4", that weighs roughly 300lbs. Is this a proper distribution of weight for this base?

Comment: The base is made out of 2" steel.

Comment: Isn’t 40” rather high for a table?

Answer (score 1):

We really can't give you a good answer to this.

It doesn't take much to make a base that can hold 300 lbs, but we have no way of knowing if you have done so. That is only the beginning.

If you put weight on the table, it has to be even stronger. If you put all that weight over one leg, that leg must be strong enough.

If you bump the table, you generate forces in a direction other than down. How hard and which way will the table be bumped over its life?

A tall table with a narrow base will be easy to tip over. How easy depends on factors like how well the feet stick to the floor and how you bump it, and how weight on the table is distributed.

Are there overhangs? Putting a heavy weight on an overhang makes a tippy table.

Given enough information, all these things can be calculated. You could then research things like how big a bump is likely to occur, and determine if the table is up to the job. But people often don't design tables to handle all these cases. They often build something and try it out and see if it works. Or maybe copy an existing table.

I made a workbench once. I didn't design it with numbers. I just made it way overbuilt. I used 4x4s for legs, and a sheet of 3/4" plywood for the top. I used 2x4's to brace it. It is held together with big bolts. It isn't very tall. It is big and heavy and hard to move around. But several friends and I could dance on it. You would have a hard time knocking it over with a sledge hammer.